# How to connect WebAppAzureStorageAccounts to WebApp using Pulumi Azure Native

Tags: azure-resource-manager, pulumi

I am trying to automate what can be done via the Azure portal with the following screen.

[image]

I have defined a [WebApp](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/web/webapp/) and a [WebAppAzureStorageAccounts](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/web/webappazurestorageaccounts/)

When trying to construct the `WebAppAzureStorageAccounts` I get the following error:

`error: parent resource does not exist for resource`

I think this is because I don't know how to associate the `WebAppAzureStorageAccounts` to the `WebApp`.

I was expecting a property named something like `StorageAccounts` or `PathMappings` to be on WebApp [SiteConfigArgs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/web/webapp/#siteconfig)

Pulumi version: 2.23.1
Language C#
Pulumi.AzureNative: 0.7.1

--- Update ---

Some code snippets... I wrap the Pulumi classes in so I can use the builder pattern with some reusable defaults.  So not your normal.

```cs
  public class WebAppAzureStorageAccountsComponent
  {

    private readonly string ComponentName;
    public WebAppAzureStorageAccounts? WebAppAzureStorageAccounts;
    public WebAppAzureStorageAccountsArgs WebAppAzureStorageAccountsArgs;
    private bool Built;
    public CustomResourceOptions? CustomResourceOptions { get; set; }

    public WebAppAzureStorageAccountsComponent
    (
      string aComponentName,
      string aShareName,
      AzureStorageInfoValueArgs aAzureStorageInfoValueArgs,
      ResourceGroup aResourceGroup,
      StorageAccountComponent aStorageAccountComponent
    )
    {
      ComponentName = aComponentName;
      WebAppAzureStorageAccountsArgs =
        new WebAppAzureStorageAccountsArgs
        {
          Name = aComponentName,
          ResourceGroupName = aResourceGroup.Name,
          Properties = new InputMap<AzureStorageInfoValueArgs>
          {
            {
              aShareName,
              aAzureStorageInfoValueArgs
            }
          }
        };
    }

    [MemberNotNull(nameof(WebAppAzureStorageAccounts))]
    public WebAppAzureStorageAccounts Build()
    {
      if (Built) throw new MultipleBuildException(nameof(WebAppAzureStorageAccountsComponent));
      Built = true;

      WebAppAzureStorageAccounts =
        new WebAppAzureStorageAccounts
        (
          ComponentName,
          WebAppAzureStorageAccountsArgs,
          CustomResourceOptions
        );

      return WebAppAzureStorageAccounts;
    }
  }
```

And a snippet from WebAppComponent

```cs
    public WebAppComponent
    (
      string aName,
      AppServicePlan aAppServicePlan,
      ResourceGroup aResourceGroup,
      string aEnvironment,
      RegistryComponent? aRegistryComponent = null,
      Input<string>? aImageName = null
    )
    {
      ComponentName = aName;
      RegistryComponent = aRegistryComponent;
      Environment = aEnvironment;

      WebAppArgsBuilder =
        new WebAppArgsBuilder
        (
          ComponentName,
          aResourceGroup.Name
        )
        {
          Kind = "app,linux",
          Location = aResourceGroup.Location,
          ServerFarmId = aAppServicePlan.Id,
        };

      List<NameValuePairArgs> appSettings = BuildAppSettings();
      WebAppArgsBuilder.SiteConfigArgsBuilder.WithAppSettings(appSettings);

      if (aImageName != null)
      {
        WebAppArgsBuilder.SiteConfigArgsBuilder.LinuxFxVersion = Output.Format($"DOCKER|{aImageName}");
        WebAppArgsBuilder.Kind = "app,linux,container";
      }
    }
```

And then snippets of the usage of these components

```cs
      CredentialApiWebAppComponent =
        new WebAppComponent
        (
          $"credential-{AspNetCoreEnvironment}-{Brand}",
          AppServicePlan,
          ResourceGroup,
          AspNetCoreEnvironment,
          RegistryComponent,
          credentialImageName
        );

      CredentialApiWebAppComponent.Build();
    ...
      var TailsAzureStorageInfoValueArgs = new AzureStorageInfoValueArgs
      {
        AccessKey = StorageAccountComponent.PrimaryStorageKey!,
        AccountName = StorageAccountComponent.StorageAccount!.Name!,
        MountPath = "/tails",
        ShareName = "tails",
        Type = AzureStorageType.AzureFiles
      };

      var webAppAzureStorageAccountsComponent =
        new WebAppAzureStorageAccountsComponent
        (
          aComponentName: "TailsMapping",
          aShareName: "tails",
          aAzureStorageInfoValueArgs: TailsAzureStorageInfoValueArgs,
          aResourceGroup: ResourceGroup,
          aStorageAccountComponent: StorageAccountComponent
        );

      webAppAzureStorageAccountsComponent.Build();
```

There is nothing that references between WebAppAzureStorageAccounts to WebApp and I can't find an example online.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Some Code snippets added.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, you assign an arbitrary name to the `WebAppAzureStorageAccounts` resource. Instead, you should assign the `Name` property to the name of your web app (the parent resource). It's not the best naming choice from the Azure API but the comment says `Name of the app.`

Here is the idea that should work:

```csharp
var webApp = new WebApp("myapp", new ...);
var storage = new WebAppAzureStorageAccounts("accounts",
    new WebAppAzureStorageAccountsArgs
    {
        Name = webApp.Name,
        // ...
    });
```

This pattern is similar to all subresources of Web Apps, as shown in [this example](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/blob/master/examples/appservice/index.ts#L92-L147).

Comment: Oh man, I have another component `WebAppDiagnosticLogsConfigurationComponent` that does exactly that... Why I didn't recognize the pattern here I don't know.  Thank You!